# How to prove that the triangle areas between squares on a isosceles triangle are equal

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

**The problem**

In this figure we have an red isosceles triangle with squares attached outwardly at its sides. Prove that the area of the red triangle and the three green ones are equal.
[image: The problem illustrated]

**Solved by marty cohen**

The upper angle can be written as 2x because the whole angle is 360 degrees - 2*90 degrees - (180degrees-2x), so 360-180-180+2x=2x. Sin(2x) can be written as 2*sinx*cosx, and cosx as a/2c.

The area is then equal to (x*y*sin(x))/2 in all the triangles.

Comment: Questions presented like this as an isolated question are liable to be closed down. What you need to do is to give some context as to where the question is from, why it is interesting to you, and what thoughts you have had about solving it - an indication of how much you know (what formulae do you know for the area of a triangle?) will also help people to help you. But most people on the site are not keen to solve people's homework for them and problems which look as though they might be homework tend to get closed for this reason. (Homework is set to help people learn by doing it themselves).

Comment: I agee, but in this case It seems OP took fair amount of time on the drawing and it helps solving the problem too.

Comment: Sorry If it seemed a bit begging and homework related, that was not my intent. I am qutie new to this page and not aware of all the rules. I am taking a class about solving different math problems, and have been dealing with the pythagorean curiosity problem where the triangle is right angled. This was an attempt at specializing and hopefully generalize for all triangles. Since the problem was rather straight forward I just added it as it was, but will keep your comment in consideration for my next question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the angles
around each vertex is
$2\pi$.
Since the sum of the angles
formed by the squares is
$\pi$,
so is the sum of
the other two angles.

The result then follows
from the formula
for the area of a triangle
given two sides and
the included angle
($A=\frac12 ab\sin(t)$)
together with
$\sin(x)
=\sin(\pi-x)$.

Note that this is true
for any triangle,
not just isosceles.

Comment: Thanks a lot of your answer. This was really helpful, and a nice way to generalize it. I have been trying to prove that this is true for a right-angled triangle, and an equilateral one. This was my last spesialization, but you actually helped my generalize it aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer
which uses only geometry,
not trig.

Rotate any of the exterior triangles
90 degrees about the point of the triangle
(either direction).
The two equal sides match up
and the angles add up to
180 degrees so
the bases are on a single line.

Since the two triangles
have the same base
and the same altitude,
they have the same area.